# GAE: remote_api_shell.py uses wrong Django version

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have a Python 2.7 GAE app that uses Django 1.2.  Everything generally works fine.

I'm trying to use `remote_api_shell.py`, but when I import my `models.py`, I get this error:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=.; remote_api_shell.py APP
App Engine remote_api shell
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
The db, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
s~APP> import models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/.../models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.validators import email_re
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/core/validators.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy, ngettext
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/conf/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    self._import_settings()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in _import_settings
    raise EnvironmentError, "Environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
EnvironmentError: Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I don't know why it is using Django 0.96 here.  Especially since I think Python 2.7 supports only Django 1.2.  Here are the relevant parts of my `app.yaml`:

```
application: APP
version: prod
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

[...]

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
```

If I comment out the `from django.core.validators import email_re` line then the import succeeds.

Any idea if I am doing something wrong or if this is this a GAE bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by running these two lines once I open the remote API session:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.3')
```

Though, clearly, it's a hack. Star this issue to encourage the app engine team to fix it:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8716

Comment: It is a better hack than mine!

Comment: I find I additionally need to set my env settings path and do any additions to the python path that i'd otherwise do in my main.py

`    import sys, os
    ...
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libs'))
`

Comment: You can set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in app.yaml to simplify. And I never need to update the path, not sure why you need that. Make sure you have __init__.py file in your lib directory.

Answer (score 1):

try typing this:

```
import django
django.VERSION
```

To check the django version! I am guessing that the python console that u are running has the old version of django!

Comment: Yes, that does give 0.96!  It is importing Django from `google_appengine/lib` which also has Django 1.2 there.  Any idea how to have right Django version loaded by default?

Comment: I can hack my path, with the following line, but hopefully there is a better way: sys.path.insert(0,"/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/.../google_appengine/lib/django_1_2")

Answer (score 0):

FYI this no longer works because

```
use_library('django', '1.5')
```

now throws this error:

```
ValueError: 1.5 is not a supported version for django; supported versions are ['0.96', '1.0', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3']
```

Hopefully this is a temporary problem, but my solution was to delete (rename):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-0.96
```

to something else, then the proper version of django loads w/o any other problems.